# How to Populate a QStandardItemModel

Tags: c++, qt, qstandarditemmodel

I'm a beginner at Qt and I'm struggling to populate a `QStandardItemModel` from an XML file.

I've tried the following and the entire project runs successfully but the `QtableView` does not display the data.

Here is my `main.cpp`:

```
void readXml(const QString& fileName) {
    QFile file(fileName);
    if(!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)) {
        qDebug() << "Cannot read file" << file.errorString();
        return;
    }

    StockItems* stockitems = new StockItems;
    XmlStockItemsReader xmlReader(stockitems);

    if(!xmlReader.read(&file))
        qDebug() << "Parse error in file " << xmlReader.errorString();
    else {
        stockitems->print();
        stockitems->populateStockModel();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    StockItems si;

    //! Change this to match the path of your project
    QString path = "C:\\unisa\\cos3711\\FIConcession";
    readXml(path + "\\stockitems.xml");

    si.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

In `stockitems.cpp` I have the following function:

```
void StockItems::populateStockModel() {
    foreach(Item* item, m_items) {
        QList<QStandardItem*> newRow;

        QStandardItem *stockID = new QStandardItem(QString("%1").arg(item->stockID()));
        QStandardItem *desc = new QStandardItem(QString("%2").arg(item->desc()));
        QStandardItem *price = new QStandardItem(QString("%3").arg(item->price()));

        newRow.append(stockID);
        newRow.append(desc);
        newRow.append(price);

        stockModel->appendRow(newRow);
    }
}
```

If I do some debugging I can see that the `stockID`, `desc` and `prices` are correctly read, so the problem must lie somewhere with updating the `stockModel`.

My main `StockItems` Constructor is as follows:

```
StockItems::StockItems(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::StockItems)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    stockModel = new QStandardItemModel(0, 3);

    // Set Model Headers
    stockModel->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, "Stock ID", Qt::DisplayRole);
    stockModel->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, "Description", Qt::DisplayRole);
    stockModel->setHeaderData(2, Qt::Horizontal, "Price", Qt::DisplayRole);

    // Link Model to Table View
    ui->tvStock->setModel(stockModel);
}
```

I have an add button which contains the following `onclick` code which works as expected so I'm just not sure if I'm referencing the `stockModel` correctly.

```
QList<QStandardItem*> newRow;

QStandardItem* stockID = new QStandardItem(QString("%1").arg(ui->tbStockId->text()));
QStandardItem* desc = new QStandardItem(QString("%2").arg(ui->tbDesc->text()));
QStandardItem* price = new QStandardItem(QString("%3").arg(ui->sbPrice->text()));

newRow.append(stockID);
newRow.append(desc);
newRow.append(price);

stockModel->appendRow(newRow);
```

Finally I think this might help, my `stockitems.h` file:

```
class StockItems : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit StockItems(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~StockItems();
    void populateStockModel();
    void addItem(Item* item);
    void print() const;

private slots:
    void on_btnAdd_clicked();
    void on_btnDelete_clicked();

private:
    Ui::StockItems *ui;
    QStandardItemModel *stockModel;
    QList<Item*> m_items;
};
```

This is a lot and please let me know if I should provide anything else but I'm really lost as to how to populate this model correctly.

Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: As far as I see, this looks correct. I'd suggest writing a debug function to dump the contents of the model after you've populated it. Make sure the column and row counts are as expected and the text of each item. The problem might be in your table view setup, although that also looks OK.

Comment: I think the problem may be in the StockItems constructor where I say `stockModel = new QStandardItemModel(0, 3);` but whenever I change this it breaks...  Not sure what to do :/

Comment: I see the answer has been added. That answer is correct, and I missed that when I was reading the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `readXml` function does not populate the `StockItems` instance that you create in your `main` function, but a completely new `StockItems` instance that isn't used anywhere.

For example, instead of

```
StockItems* stockitems = new StockItems;
```

in your `readXml` function, let `readXml` take another `StockItems` argument, and use that:

```
void readXml(const QString& fileName, StockItems *stockItems) {
    // do everything here as before, except for the
    // StockItems* stockitems = new StockItems;
    ...
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    ...
    readXml(path + "\\stockitems.xml", &si);
    si.show();
    ...
}
```